# How to properly egress a services to a specific static IP address in Azure Kubernetes Service?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks

I have deployed a service with type ClusterIP in AKS. This service MUST NOT be available from outside, but it MUST communicate with external APIs through specific static public IP-address, because the IP-address was whitelisted.

How to egress only this specific service but not the whole AKS cluster? Also, if I deploy a new service, can I egress it through another static public IP-address? Any help or suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible. you can only "give" a static IP address to a node(s) on the cluster. not to a service.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-outbound-connections#scenarios